# Cannot access lines based of header poco class

Tags: vb.net, filehelpers

I am having the weirdest of errors.

```
Dim lines As List(Of NewOrderCsv) = (From record In _records Where record.Ticket2 = orderHeaderRow.Ticket2)
```

Their error is happening here on my declaration of the lines object

```
    For Each line As NewOrderCsv In lines

        CreateSopOrderLine(orderHeaderRow, newMcsOrder, newMcsOrder.AnalysisCode1, orderHeaderRow.String15, newMcsOrder.AnalysisCode1, newMcsOrder.ContactName, orderHeaderRow.String3, line)

    Next
```

I am mostly a c# programer so forgive me if this is easy in vb.net

> {"Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereListIterator`1[AveryIntegration.Common.CSV.Records.NewOrderCsv]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AveryIntegration.Common.CSV.Records.NewOrderCsv]'."}

The class for the NewOrderCSV is a file helpers

```
Namespace CSV.Records
<DelimitedRecord(",")>
Public Class NewOrderCsv
    <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public String2 As String

    <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public String3 As String

    <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public String4 As String

    <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public String5 As String

    <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public String10 As String

    <FieldConverter(GetType(CustomStringConvertor))>
    <FieldQuoted>
    Public String15 As String

    Public Decimal1 As Decimal

    Public Decimal5 As Decimal

    Public Decimal8 As Decimal

    Public Decimal9 As Decimal

    Public Decimal10 As Decimal

    Public Date1 As DateTime

    Public Ticket2 As Integer

    <DebuggerNonUserCode>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should have an error in `Dim lines As List(Of NewOrderCsv)`, telling you that you cannot convert an `Enumerable(something)` into a `List(Of Something)`.

Comment: @Jimi all the debugger told me was about WhereListIterator1 which was actually in correct in a way .

Comment: @Jim as you can see I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

My method was returning a single item I replaced the line with when it should been cast as a list cant believe I didn't see that.

```
Dim lines As List(Of NewOrderCsv) = (From record In _records Where record.Ticket2 = orderHeaderRow.Ticket2).ToList()
```